# Customize the drop box element selection of AutoCompleteBox in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, autocompletebox

I am new to WPF and right now I am trying to figure out how to customize the AutoCompleteBox.

I want my AutoCompleteBox to be able to enter several text elements separated by "; ".

For example, the text box can have:

```
Apple; Banana; Cat
```

I have already customized my filter method, which will enable a new search after user enters the "; ".

But the annoying thing is, if I select an element from the drop down box, the original text will be replaced by the selected element.

For example, the text box have this at first, and the drop down box has the "Banana" in it:

```
Apple; Ba
```

Then I choose the "Banana" in the drop down box, the old text will be replaced:

```
Banana
```

But I want the text box to be like this:

```
Apple; Banana
```

Is there a way to override the selection event of the drop down box, so that it could keep the original text? Or, is there any other way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can use selectionchanged event,something like this:

```
 <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtInput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="154,36,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="327"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="154,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Apple"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Pear"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Banana"/>
        </ComboBox>

    </Grid>



private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(comboBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                string tmp = txtInput.Text;
                if (tmp.LastIndexOf(';') > 0)
                {
                    txtInput.Text = tmp.Substring(0, tmp.LastIndexOf(';') + 1) + ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem).Content;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtInput.Text += ";" +((ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem).Content;
                }

            }
        }
```

it is just a example,you should analysis your string and do something,for an another example:

you input `Apple;Ba` and select `Banana` in combobox, certainly, replace Ba to Banana.But if you select `Pear`,are you sure to replace `Ba` to `Pear` ? you may use string.StartWith decide whether replace it or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access to a telerik control suite it has an auto complete control with-in it. It implements all of the functionality you have outlined out of the box. Here is a link [Telerik Auto Complete](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radcombobox-features-autocomplete.html)

As a side note I do not work for telerik nor do I get anything from plugging them. I just really like working with their products!